# How to get track changes version of document back after after closing document?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, macbook-pro, issue-tracking

I'm wondering if there's a way to get tracked changes back after accepting them, saving the document as a new title, and closing out the document? I'm working in Word on a new MacBook Pro running OS X 10.8.4.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 you can right click on the Word document (.docx) and click on the tab previous versions. There you will see all the changes you made to your document. Check if this works also on Mac OS too.

[image: windows 7 restore previous versions right click]

---

I think this is how you can do it in OS X

1. Hold the pointer to the right of the document title, click the arrow, and then choose Browse All Versions.
2. Click tick marks along the timeline to browse versions.
3. Do one of the following:
   To restore your document to a previous version, display the version, and then click Restore.

   To duplicate a version in a new document, display the version, press the Option key, and then click “Restore a Copy.”

   To delete a version, display the version, hold the pointer to the right of the title, click the arrow, and then choose Delete This Version.

   To delete all versions, press the Option key while holding the pointer to the right of a version’s title, click the arrow, and then choose Delete Old Versions.

To leave your document as is, without changes, click Done.